# How can I calculate frequency (not count) when drawing windrose diagram using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a windrose diagram using ggplot of R.
The code below showed count of data, not frequency of specific range (e.g., 2-4 m/s).
How can I improve the code to draw stacked bars showing frequency of each wind speed class (0-2, 2-4, 4-6, 6-8 m/s) blowing from each of 16 direction?
I assume cumulative sum of frequency of all wind speed class (0-2, 2-4, 4-6, 6-8 m/s) in all of 16 wind direction= 100%.
Is using `geom_bar` right in this purpose?

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(reshape)
 wind.data <- read.table("09Aug-wind.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
 wind.data <- melt(wind.data, id="wd")
 wind <- ggplot(wind.data, aes(x = wd, y = value, fill = variable))
 wind.bar <- wind + geom_bar(breaks = seq(0,360), width = 22.5, col_pal = "Greys", 
             stat = "identity") + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)
 wind.bar + coord_polar() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360), 
             breaks = c(0, 22.5, 45, 67.5, 90, 112.5, 135, 157.5, 180,
                       202.5, 225, 247.5, 270, 292.5, 315, 337.5),
             labels=c("N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW",
                      "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"))
```

Beginning of data frame before `melt()` ("09Aug-wind.txt"; wd = wind direction in degree, ws = wind speed in m/s)

```
wind.data
     ws    wd            time
1   0.4 202.5   2009/8/1 1:00
2   0.6 135.0   2009/8/1 2:00
3   0.6 202.5   2009/8/1 3:00
4   1.2 180.0   2009/8/1 4:00
5   0.6 157.5   2009/8/1 5:00
6   0.4 112.5   2009/8/1 6:00
7   0.6 135.0   2009/8/1 7:00
8   0.5  90.0   2009/8/1 8:00
9   0.4  90.0   2009/8/1 9:00
10  1.0  90.0  2009/8/1 10:00
11  2.7 135.0  2009/8/1 11:00
12  3.4 135.0  2009/8/1 12:00
13  1.7 112.5  2009/8/1 13:00
```

Beginning of data frame after `melt()`

```
wind.data
        wd variable           value
1    202.5       ws             0.4
2    135.0       ws             0.6
3    202.5       ws             0.6
4    180.0       ws             1.2
5    157.5       ws             0.6
6    112.5       ws             0.4
7    135.0       ws             0.6
8     90.0       ws             0.5
9     90.0       ws             0.4
10    90.0       ws               1
11   135.0       ws             2.7
12   135.0       ws             3.4
13   112.5       ws             1.7
```

The output of the preceding code is available on the link below:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7EB3C557A7C8D971!2878&authkey=!AGgR_x2BI58Ir94&ithint=file%2cemf

Comment: Looks like some syntax errors here: `wind.bar + coord_polar() + +  scale_x_continuous(....)` ?

Comment: Thanks. I removed the waste plus sign.

Comment: I would try with `cut()` to transform the column `value` in a factor and then plot the frequency of every factor.